# Chainlink Function request realtime API data encodeUint256 invalid input

Tags: fetch, solidity, chainlink

I try to write a source.js my chainlink function, but it seem that there problem with the data type. I'm trying to get the "`footprint`" data from the real time API (link below).

Since this API doesn't require any api key, I've got my source.js as below. I use the "`npx hardhat functions-simulate`" to run the script and The error I'm getting is :

Error message returned to client contract:

> encodeUint256 invalid input.

Please help.

```
const config = {
  url: "https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544",
}

const response = Functions.makeHttpRequest(config)
return Functions.encodeUint256(Math.round(response.footprint))
```

Answer (score 0):

the makeHttpRequest is an async function and youre missing the async keyword
it should be

const response = await Functions.makeHttpRequest(config)

right now response.footprint is undefined since its still waiting for a response.